# Jquery Dialog 'Stack overflow at line 0' issue in IE 8

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-dialog

I have a dialog from which one other jquery dialog is called, The issue is when i call the second popup's open function i am getting an error like "Stack overflow at line 0" in IE 8. In other browsers it works fine, I found that its because of event triggering in a lop. is there any solution for this problem

```
 function openPopupNew() {

      var popup = jQuery( "#terms_dialog_1" ).dialog({
                                autoOpen: false,
                                resizable: false,
                                height:150,
                                width:250,
                                modal: true,
                                closeOnEscape:true,
                                show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                                 position:['top','center'],
                                buttons: [
                                {
                                    text:okButton,
                                    click: function() {
                                        jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                    }
                                }]

                            });
                            popup.dialog( "open" );
    }                       
    openPopupNew();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226102/stack-overflow-in-line-0-on-internet-explorer

Comment: Regarding the particular case - is this code declared in global scope ?